# How to put a delay between the initial ValueAnimator and the reverse repeat

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I have a two line textview where I am attempting to do the following:

1. when data arrives, fade out the second line *only*
2. change the data presented in the second line
3. fade the second line back in

I am currently using the following code to accomplish this:

```
ValueAnimator alphaAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(255,0).setDuration(1000);
alphaAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
alphaAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
alphaAnim.setStartDelay(500);
```

```
alphaAnim.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
            int alpha = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            int newColor = binding.ForegroundSpanText.getCurrentTextColor() & 0x00ffff | (alpha <<24);
            SpannableString tempStringHolder = binding.getAnimString();
            if(fadingSpan !=null){
                tempStringHolder.removeSpan(fadingSpan);
            }
            fadingSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(newColor);
            tempStringHolder.setSpan(fadingSpan, tempStringHolder.toString().indexOf("\n"), tempStringHolder.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            if(Integer.toHexString(newColor).equals("1000000") && !tempStringHolder.toString().equals("This is my test text with lots of text\n and this is the new text that will animate in!!")){
                animStringHolder = new SpannableString("This is my test text with lots of text\n and this is the new text that will animate in!!");
                binding.setAnimString(animStringHolder);
                binding.executePendingBindings();
            }else{
                binding.setAnimString(tempStringHolder);
            }
        });
```

The issues I am currently running into are:

- The change between the initial text and the text I change to is still visible because the reverse animation happens immediately, so I am looking for a way to add a delay between the reversal. I realize that this could be done with a second animator but was hoping someone might have some idea of how to accomplish this without.
- Also if anyone has a better way to set the data/check if the end point of the first animator has been reached that would be awesome, I tried to override the onAnimationEnd() function but that occurs when the entire animation finishes, meaning after the reverse repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In further research I found onAnimationRepeat() which is part of [AnimationListenerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter#onAnimationRepeat(android.animation.Animator)). So the code to make this a part of what I posted originally would look like:

```
alphaAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){
                animStringHolder = new SpannableString("This is my test text with lots of text\n and this is the new text that will animate in!!");
                binding.setAnimString(animStringHolder);
            }
        });
```